# read json in python3 from relative path

Tags: json, file, python-3.x

This is my project structure:

```
main
-/data/data.json
-/a/b/c.py
main.py
```

data folder an a folder are in main folder which is the root of my project.
I need to read data.json from c.py in python3
what would be my string in open()?

```
file = open('./data/data.json')
```

this works in windows but not linux

Answer (score 1):

Up two folders and then in `data/data.json`:

```
with open('../../data/data.json') as f:
    ...
```

*If you are on Windows, swap slashes with backslashes*.